# Maven require inclusion of file when building JAR file

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I need to include a file in the built JAR file from Maven.
So I followed this reference doc and added an  element in my pom.xml: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

This however includes the file if it exists - I need to make this file a requirement for the end result JAR file. Is there a way to specify that the inclusion of the file is mandatory?

Comment: I don't understand your question: Either the file is needed so you put it into `src/main/resources` and it will be packaged into the resulting jar or you don't ?

Comment: The file should not be in the `src/main/resources` path in my case. It should be at the root of the generated JAR file (`.`, not `./src/main/resources`), hence why I have to manually include it with a maven directive.

Comment: The files of `src/main/resources` are copied to the root of the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an enforcer rule:

https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html

This checks whether a file exists and breaks the build otherwise.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks! It would be cool if another plugin wasn't necessary, but oh well..